# The specified type member 'LastHistoryEntry' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I get the mentioned error message for the following query:

```
public IQueryable<StockItem> NotTaken()
        {
            return this.Queryable.Where(itm => itm.LastHistoryEntry.StockItemStatus != StockItemStatus.Taken && itm.LastHistoryEntry.StockItemStatus != StockItemStatus.TakenReserved);
        }
```

The member LastHistoryEntry is in the StockItem class with type StockItemHistory:

```
public StockItemHistory LastHistoryEntry
```

Here is a part of the StockItemHistory class with the StockItemStatus:

```
 public class StockItemHistory
    {
        public long StockItemId { get; set; }

        public StockItemStatus StockItemStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

I looked at a lot of similar questions with this error message, but they didn't seem to help me in my situation.

Could you also please provide a simple explanation, why this problem occurs, to understand where LINQ has a problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason you would be getting that is if that `StockItemHistory` class is not currently mapped to any table in the database. Then LINQ to Entities, when trying to process that into a SQL query, has no idea where it should be looking to resolve that part, and bombs.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. What can I do so LINQ to Entities recognices the StockItemHistory class?

Comment: It would need to be a table in your database.